# Create subsets from Python list with suffix

Tags: python

I am trying to segment python main list to sub-lists with appropriate suffix. For example, 
the Main List looks something like

```
M = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to create a sub-lists like below

```
M_1_3 = [1,2,3]
M_4_6 = [4,5,6]
```

This is just for example as I do have a list of thousand elements. I tried the below 'For loop' but not working

```
for i in range(0,len(main_list),50):
    start = i
    end = i+50
    'sub_list_'+str(start)+'_'+str(end) = main_list[start:end]
```

Comment: Python indexes starts from 0, so it's adviseable to use M_0_2 and M_3_5 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't encourage dynamic variables. Use a dictionary:

```
sub_lists = {}
for i in range(0,len(main_list),50):
    start = i
    end = i+50
    sub_lists[str(start)+'_'+str(end)] = main_list[start:end]
```

And using a tuple is better than creating a string from integers:

```
sub_lists = {}
for i in range(0,len(main_list),50):
    start = i
    end = i+50
    sub_lists[(start, end)] = main_list[start:end]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force an assignment by using `exec`:

```
main_list = list(range(200))
for i in range(0,200,50):
    start = i
    end = i+50
    exec('sub_list_'+str(start)+'_'+str(end) +'= main_list[start:end]')

print(sub_list_0_50)
```

However, it's not a good practice in Python.